# Adding the full date to a Squarespace blog post

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, squarespace

What custom code can I add to squarespace to have the full day publish to a blog post? To look like this: WEDNESDAY, APR 29, 2020 on each blog post?

This is what I have currently:
APR 29, 2020

```
<time class="dt-published blog-meta-item blog-meta-item--date" datetime="Apr 28" pubdate="" data-content-field="published-on">
              <span>Apr 29, 2020</span>
            </time>
```

Comment: With Squarespace-related questions, it usually best to include, at minimum, what template you are using. Even better would be to provide a link to the page in question, if possible.What template are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) method in JavaScript.

Basically I have just inserted each day and month to array of strings and extracted the current date through `Date()` function.

```js
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + " " + d.getFullYear();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```